# Xamarin Add click event in custom renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using this Drag/Drop code: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/DragViewSample/tree/master/DragViewSample/DragViewSample

This works great, but now I want to not just be able to drag/drop an image, but also a click action. The function needs probably be done in the Custom renderer in this part of the code:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    float x = e.RawX;
    float y = e.RawY;
    var dragView = Element as DraggableView.DraggableView;
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            if (dragView.DragMode == DragMode.Touch)
            {
                if (!touchedDown)
                {
                    if (firstTime)
                    {
                        originalX = GetX();
                        originalY = GetY();
                        firstTime = false;
                    }
                    dragView.DragStarted();
                }

                touchedDown = true;
            }
            dX = x - this.GetX();
            dY = y - this.GetY();
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            if (touchedDown)
            {
                if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Horizontal)
                {
                    SetX(x - dX);
                }

                if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Vertical)
                {
                    SetY(y - dY);
                }

            }
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            touchedDown = false;
            dragView.DragEnded();
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
            touchedDown = false;
            break;
    }
    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
}
```

But I have no idea how I can add a Click function to it, without moving the image.
Just for the idea, I want a popup when I click on the image and still be able to drag/drop when I hold it.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of fine things that one needs to do here to make it work in a real good way and if you expect that then the question needs to be closed as this is not the site where someone else writes the code for you.

Assuming you are fine with that, I'll give you just very basic idea on how to do it.

The key is in recording the `DateTime` of `touchedDown = true;`and comparing it to the `DateTime` of `touchedDown = false;` and if it is below some threshold calling it 'click'. If you do just this there will be some artifacts but you need to resolve them.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't really looking for the code, but more the idea like this.... You are really helpful!